# IF function with time

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

Picture of cells

(https://i.gyazo.com/ac6db30cccd2047df33560125a8177a1.png)

The cells content:

C1: 15:00
C2: 22:00
C1 and C2 are start time and end time on a work day.

and FYI for those not knowing what these numbers might mean
22:00 = 10pm
10:00 = 10am

My function on cell C3 should be following:
If I am working between C1 and C2 then I want it to make it calculate from C3 the amount of hours from 19.00, in my case I have 22:00 in that cell so it should say 3 on C3 when I have C2= 22:00. How to do it?

Right now I have this simple function which I just tried in C3 `=IF(C2=TIMEVALUE("22:00:00");3;0)` and it does not seem to work, it says 0 on the cell, which means it does not really know that it says 22:00 on C2.

Comment: The `TIMEVALUE` function converts your time to Serial so it will not know what 22:00:00 means. I think you want to use the `NOW()` function to test if a time is between the start and end times.

Comment: Okay, so if I make it "=IF(C3="22:00:00";3;0)" it still will not work

Comment: (Made an edit to the post), but to simplify it to you guys. I want C3 to become = 3 if I have C2 = 22:00:00 (formated cell as time)

Comment: It would be awesome if I could make C3 to count hours from 19:00 and forth, if you know any function to make that happen

Comment: You don't need to simplify, the respondents in this forum are pretty smart.  Here's a formula that works: `D1=IF(AND(C1>A1,C1<B1),3,0)`.  A1 is your start time, B1 is your end time, C1 is whatever time you are testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use a fixed time in a formula, you could do `=IF(C2=VALUE("22:00:00");"It's 10pm";"other time")` - you actually got close, but it's `VALUE` I would try.

When you want to figure out how long after 7pm you've stayed in, try `=(C2-VALUE("19:00:00"))*24` (and format the cell as number)

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me, but I was not able to describe my problem really well. I have it fixed now, just need one more thing I need help with, and that is to be able to count hours and minutes in a cell as "3,5" instead of "3:30", the formatting tool did not quite help

Comment: sry for the confusion then; just added calcing the time diff to the answer. Hope this helps you move fw...

Comment: Thanks, works great!! :) But stumbled upon a little problem, if I left a lot earlier, let us say I started at 07.00 and left at 12:30 then it will calculate as -6,5 :/

Comment: I found a solution to my problem through your answers and Sam´s answers. I compiled what I learn´t from both of you guys and used common sense to get it to work. Huge thanks! :D

Comment: Your recent reply made my own messy code much nicer and it works like a charm, thanks a lot! :)

Comment: @ViktorKrum Instead of having the (Solved) in the title, you should accept the answer by clicking the gray checkmark sign. And BTW, remove the (Solved) from the title, please.

Answer (score 0):

Entering time inside the formula presents problems due to the formatting as the colon will make the formula think you want to do something else and quotes will change the format to text.

Here's a formula that works: `D1=IF(AND(C1>A1,C1<B1),3,0)` where A1 is your start time, B1 is your end time, C1 is whatever time you are testing.

To calculate the difference between current time `C1` and the end of your work-day, then just change the 3 to `SUM(C1,-B1)` and format as a time value (HH:MM).

To add cuteness: change C1 to calculate the current time as HH:MM:SS so you can tell exactly how long until you go home from work: C1=`TIMEVALUE(HOUR(NOW())&":"&MINUTE(NOW())&":"&SECOND(NOW()))` (NOTE: there's probably a more elegant way to do this - I'll post later if I figure it out)

Comment: The formula did not quite work. Here is a snapshot: https://i.gyazo.com/7f5b1da31577e992f276130fa21f369c.png
I appreciate you trying to help me, when I am a newbie

Comment: I fixed it, I needed to add semicolons instead ´=IF(AND(B2>C2);3;0)´. Thanks the function now works, but if you might help me with my main problem which will make this formula work professionaly, I want it to count from 19:00 the amount of hours and minutes until 00:00. So if end time is 22.30 then it will say 3.5 in D1 cell

Comment: Now I understand the purpose of the IF statement output  That's easy to do.  I'll edit and re-post.

Comment: don't forget to accept if it works; and if a better solution doesn't come along (highly likely)

Comment: No need to figure anything else out more than how to get D1 to show the hours as 3,5 instead of 3:30, I have D1 formated as t:mm
To explain what D calculates: It calculates the amount of hours I am being overpaid due to late shift, it starts counting from 19.00
I want to be able to then sum up all the cells in column D and have another cell calculate it (That I can do, with the sum formula)

I appreciate your help a lot, I upvoted your answer! :D

Comment: Details!  Change formula ini D1 to `=IF(AND(C1>=A1,C1<=B1),SUM(C1,-A1),0)` where A1 is the overtime start (thought it was a shift-start earlier), and B1 is the End time; then set formatting to Custom then `hh,mm`

Comment: I found a solution to my problem through your answers and Sebastian Rothbucher´s answers. I compiled what I learn´t from both of you guys and used common sense to get it to work. Huge thanks! :D